# Salesforce chatbot Post Survey Option disabled

Tags: community, einstein-chatbot, salesforce-survey

Can anyone guide on how to enable the Chatbot Post survey option? Do I need a License for a Post chat survey?

[image]

Surveys are already enabled in Org.
[image]

Comment: As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_configure_post_chat_survey.htm&type=5 , the post chat survey feature is available with the Salesforce Feedback Management license.Can you confirm if you have this license?

Comment: Thanks, @Swetha for the quick response. currently, I don't have it. that's all I wanted to confirm

Comment: Happy I could help. I will add my comment as an answer so that others facing the same issue might find it helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_configure_post_chat_survey.htm&type=5 , the post-chat survey feature is available with the Salesforce Feedback Management license. With this license, you will be able to see the survey option.

Thanks